# Time ordering nucleon-nucleon scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-theorem

I am trying to compute the nucleon scattering $\psi \psi \rightarrow \psi \psi$ described by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
|i\rangle=\sqrt{2 E_{p_{1}}} \sqrt{2 E_{p_{2}}} a^{\dagger}\left(\mathbf{p}_{1}\right) a^{\dagger}\left(\mathbf{p}_{2}\right)|0\rangle \equiv\left|p_{1}, p_{2}\right\rangle \\
|f\rangle=\sqrt{2 E_{q_{1}}} \sqrt{2 E_{q_{2}}} a^{\dagger}\left(\mathbf{q}_{1}\right) a^{\dagger}\left(\mathbf{q}_{2}\right)|0\rangle \equiv\left|q_{1}, q_{2}\right\rangle
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are the incoming nucleons' 4 -momenta and $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ are the outgoing nucleons' 4-momenta. I get rid of the trivial contribution by looking at $\langle f|S-1| i\rangle$ at second order:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(-i g)^{2}}{2} \int d^{4} x \int d^{4} y \mathrm{~T} \psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi(x) \phi(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(y) \phi(y)
\end{equation}

Using Wick's theorem as there is a time-ordered string of operators:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{T} \psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi(x) \phi(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(y) \phi(y)=D_{\mathrm{F}}^{\phi}(x-y): \psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(y)
\end{equation}
where $D_{\mathrm{F}}^{\phi}(x-y)$ is the Feynman propagator obtained by contracting $\phi(x)\phi(y)$.

Thus,
\begin{equation}
D_{\mathrm{F}}^{\phi}(x-y)
\left\langle f\left|: \psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(y):\right| i\right\rangle=D_{\mathrm{F}}^{\phi}(x-y)\left\langle q_{1}, q_{2}\left|: \psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(y):\right| p_{1}, p_{2}\right\rangle
\end{equation}

Now, in the book I am following, they start to compute the integral of the scattering as shown below:
\begin{equation}
\int_{x, y} \frac{\left\langle q_{1}, q_{2}\left|\psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(x) \psi(y)\right| p_{1}, p_{2}\right\rangle}{\sqrt{2 E_{p_{1}}} \sqrt{2 E_{p_{2}}} \sqrt{2 E_{q_{1}}} \sqrt{2 E_{q_{2}}}}
\end{equation}

I can see they have gone from $\left\langle q_{1}, q_{2}\left|: \psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(y):\right| p_{1}, p_{2}\right\rangle$ to $\left\langle q_{1}, q_{2}\left|\psi^{\dagger}(x) \psi^{\dagger}(y) \psi(x) \psi(y)\right| p_{1}, p_{2}\right\rangle$ but I do not know how they did it. Any explanation?

I have tried to see how the latter equation is equivalent to the previous one, i.e. since $\psi \propto (a^{\dagger} + b)$:
\begin{equation}
\psi^{\dagger}\psi^{\dagger}\psi\psi \propto (a + b^{\dagger})(a + b^{\dagger})
(a^{\dagger} + b)
(a^{\dagger} + b)
\end{equation}
where you have creation operators on the left (like $a$ from the first $\psi^{\dagger}$) which does not make sense if it is supposed to be normal-ordered. Why do I get this?

Comment: That's the definition of normal ordering. Anything between the colons (two ":" operators) is normal ordered, meaning that all creation operators are moved to the far left.

Comment: My understanding is that the normal ordering colons change the ordering of the actual creation\annhilation operators, so the normal ordering colons doesn´t change  $:\psi \psi^{\dagger}:$ to $\psi^{\dagger}\psi$ but normal orders the expression $:\psi \psi^{\dagger}: = :(a^{\dagger} + b)(a + b^{\dagger}): =a^{\dagger} a+ a^{\dagger} b^{\dagger} +ba + b^{\dagger} b  \neq \psi^{\dagger}\psi$, so wouldn´t the above explanation make the above derivation incorrect? @Hosein

Comment: Well, technically you are correct, but since $b$ are anti-fermion operators they only contribute if your initial or final states have anti-particles, otherwise they will only contribute to disconnected graphs which are not important for scattering amplitudes. In this sense, we can effectively say $\psi \sim a$ . I also think that you should take $\psi = a+b^\dagger$ or move $\psi^\dagger$ to right otherwise the expression is not normal ordered.

Comment: Taking $\psi=a+b^{\dagger}$, we would get $\psi^{\dagger} \psi$ contains a term like $bb^{\dagger} $, which isn't normal ordered, so I actually get that either order are not normal ordered. Also about your earlier explanation, since we have multiple $\psi$ terms wouldn´t the $b$´s contained in them contribute via the other $b^{\dagger}$´s in $\psi^{\dagger}$? @Hosein

Comment: Yes, you would get $b b^\dagger$ but these terms won't contribute to your final answer. This is also an answer to your second point, all terms that contain $b$ or $b^\dagger$ won't contribute to the scattering process you are considering. To put it in other words, if you do the calculation your way or the way the book says, your final answers (=scattering amplitude, after throwing disconnected terms away) will be similar. The book just has taken a detour.